# Superclass and Subclass Java

Tags: java, subclass, superclass

I have my superclass called "BossCraft" which includes a void method labeled "move".
I also have a class that extends BossCraft called SharkBoss, which also has a void "move" method.

Is it possible to somehow call the SharkBoss's "move" method into the higher BossCraft method?

```
public class BossCraft
{
   public void move
   {
      //SharkBoss's move should go here
   }
}
public class SharkBoss extends BossCraft
{
   public void move
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Ahh, what do you mean by 'Is it possible to somehow call the SharkBoss's "move" method into the higher BossCraft method?' The idea behind inheritance is so you can define all the code for moving in BossCraft, then you can call `SharkBoss.move()` and it will run the move code from BossCraft, is this what you mean?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `super.move()` (`super.` means calling (a method of) the superclass)

If you want to do the reverse - call the subclass from superclass - it's not possible. The superclass does not know (and should not know) of the existence if its subclasses.

Note that your definitions are syntactically incorrect - you should have brackets - `move()`

Comment: I think he is trying to do the opposite.

Comment: possible..but he should improve his sentence, it can mean either (and actually doesn't mean anything right now :) ). I added a sentence about that anyway

Comment: if he wants to do it in reverse, he could use it at abstract class (and maybe rewrite a code a little)?

Comment: yes. But it depends on what he wants to do. I answered the immediate question I understood :)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
super.move();
```

It will call the move() function of its parent (i.e. its superclass-instance)!

Answer (score 0):

I you want to call parent's method, user super keyword
If you want to call child's method, I'd take a look at Abstract classes

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
BossCraft craft = new SharkBoss();
// Actually calls SharkBoss.nove
craft.move();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be doing this. The whole point of inheritance is that SharkBoss is always a BossCraft, but a BossCraft may or may not be a SharkBoss. Methods on the SharkBoss craft should only be applicable to a SharkBoss.

If you call 'move' on a SharkBoss then the SharkBoss move will be called without you having to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply cast to SharkBoss in the move method of the superclass :

```
public class BossCraft {
   public void move(){
       //SharkBoss's move should go here
   SharkBoss s = (SharkBoss) this;
   s.move();
   }
}
```

However the very principle of using subclasses is that it should be a one-way relationship, superclasses shouldn't know about their subclasses. I would advise you to refactor.

Comment: That still will not work. A cast does no change the type of the object, it merely allows the code to compile. This code would end up with a StackOverflow :D